# How can God have a human feeling?

Tags: allah, belief

For example, God can get angry according to Quran. For me, this is a human feeling and a weakness. I don't understand. How can God have a human feeling, which also happened to be a weakness?

Comment: He is forgiving and merciful as well, and so is possible for humans to be.

Comment: Allah is not like human but we can not do not use words for communication.

Comment: A human Gets angry for his benefit and his lost, but when god is angry He will never lost anything and not get any benefit. How can you compare human anger with god anger. God will become angry when you hurt someone else .and you will become angry when you got hurt. Think again before comparing.

Answer (score 6):

Actually a big mistake muslims/non-muslims make, is that they consider that God and human beings have SAME type/nature of attributes... For example, God also gets Angry and Happy, God also feels etc, but we have to know that they are all GODLY attributes, and they are NOT same or Equal to Human attributes. For example, when a human gets angry, then he gets upset, gets depressed, lose control, and can do harm to himself or to others as well but thats not true in case of God, because God is not human.

So in short, God ONLY has same name of the attributes, but Not the attributes themselves in nature as well.

A human Gets angry for his benefit and his lost, but when god is angry He will never lost anything and not get any benefit. How can you compare human anger with god anger. God will become angry when you hurt someone else .and you will become angry when you got hurt. Think again before comparing.

Comment: can you give any example what happens when god gets angry ??

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid `Say: "Shall I point out to you something much worse than this, (as judged) by the treatment it received from Allah. those who incurred the curse of Allah and His wrath, those of whom some He transformed into apes and swine, those who worshipped evil;- these are (many times) worse in rank, and far more astray from the even path!"` [5:60]

Comment: which is anger , how is this ANGER ATTRIBUTE different from human ANGER?
@hus787 : I know the Almighty can do anything , much worse in any sense , but i just wanted Farhan's clarifications of different attribute

Comment: i dont see a difference when a humans get angry they can harm each other but if god is angry on you, then you are in the worst case possible

Comment: Sidux: To which God you are referring to? in my view, you are not referring to God, but your self made view of a Evil,Powerful God,who when gets angry, does all the senseless Unujust acts.

Comment: @Farhan it's not my view it's realty u can even see this by reading quran

Comment: @Farhan you are on way to an apophatic theology but not there yet (not sure though). To be inquisitive, might I ask you to explain - based on your doctrine of _Unlikeness_ - the nature of _knowledge of God_?

Answer (score 0):

Ok So I agree With Bro Farhan , who says that Allah's wrath is not similar to Human Anger...In the sense that a human loses control when angry...Allah doesn't lose control when he is angry.

Imagine a Robot that a scientist creates and programs it to do certain tasks a certain way.
If that Robot goes against the rules of that scientist and disownS the scientist by saying he didn't create me , I was created by someone else or came into existence on my own , What would the Scientist do?

He will say you know what , the Robot I have created is crap...I should dismantle it , dump it and destroy it.

We Humans being the Creation of Allah(SWT) , the atheists amongst us say that their creator doesn't exist!
Some of them say We were created not by ALLAH(SWT) but other gods.
Humans on the face of the earth do EVERYTHING that has been prohibited by Allah and IGNORE EVERYTHING that has been commanded by ALLAH(SWT)

EVEN THEN , ALLAH (SWT) gives you a chance to live , EVEN THEN HE(SWT) provides you with food , water , shelter!!

IT IS ONLY BECAUSE ALLAH(SWT) KNOWS HOW TO CONTROL HIS ANGER AND ONLY BECAUSE HIS MERCY IS FAR GREATER THAN HIS WRATH!!!

IF IT WAS NOT FOR HIS MERCY , EVERY DISBELIEVER WOULD HAVE BEEN DESTROYED.

HOPE THIS ANSWERS THE QUESTION.

Comment: You just said it you will destroy your robot and say maybe i was wrong programming it, you will not keep him alive and torture him !

Comment: Isn't it the Mercy of Allah that people still have the ability to type such comments and their fingers are not cut off, or they still have the ability to see and he doesn't take their vision away. So Actually he is being MERCIFUL and NOT torturing his creation!!!

Comment: there is no proof that god is not a human creation and i don't understand why people say he gave what to eat or so, he created the need of eating in the first place, you really aren't asking these questions to yourself, the proof is that you just talked about cuting off my fingers, really ? if islam is elimanating the mind and act with fear and obedience to people who tells you god is like this or that, then i don't need it.

Comment: Please read my comment carefully, it says , you have the ability to deny him, the freedom of speech and freedom of having your own views , Why? because you denying Him(SWT) will not change the truth... and you harm only yourself by doing so...and that is why he DOES NOT get so angry as to cut off your fingers when you type such comments. As the one who Denys is already Doomed in the Hereafter , and that Punishment would be unending. But He(SWT) gives you a chance to come to the truth , throughout your lives till you die and that is his MERCY.